# How to install intel-undervolt and linux-intel-undervolt-tool on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, intel-graphics, intel

How to install `intel-undervolt` and `linux-intel-undervolt-tool` referenced in this [Arch wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_15_9560#Undervolt_intel_CPU_and_GPU)?

Comment: Both packages mentioned in the article seem to be based on [this github repo](https://github.com/mihic/linux-intel-undervolt), and there are a number of tools based on it (e.g. [this](https://github.com/hedgepigdaniel/linux-intel-undervolt-tool/), [this](https://github.com/georgewhewell/undervolt),  [this](https://github.com/tiziw/iuvolt)). According to the latter, the only requirements should be `msr-tools` and `bc`, which are both available on Ubuntu 18.04. So I suggest you try one of the tools and tell us if it worked!

Comment: [This repository](https://github.com/georgewhewell/undervolt) works incredibly well